# Separation space between controls disappeared after setting bootstrap in my project

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I am working on a Rails project and I just added bootstrap to take advantage of some styles. I confirmed that it is working correctly because I performed some tests styling a table and defining cols for the grid system for example. However, I have noticed an issue which I will explain based on the code below. As you can see, there is an HTML table with 2 rows to let a user type email and password. Before including bootstrap in my project, both text fields showed a separation space between them. After including bootstrap, there is no separation space. I am including an image so you can see how both text field appear one above the other without any spacing.

I will very much appreciate your feedback.

```
<div>
<%= form_tag(access_attempt_login_path, :method => :post) do %>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><%= label_tag(:email) %></td>
            <td><%= text_field_tag(:email, params[:email]) %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><%= label_tag(:password) %></td>
            <td><%= password_field_tag(:password) %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><%= submit_tag("Log In") %></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

<% end %>
</div>
```

[image: Image showing issue]

Comment: Because when you use Bootstrap tables, you need to use their specific classes to make it look nice. See http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables

Comment: Thank you. I am now using Bootstrap classes and also I created my own ones and this issue was successfully fixed.